# generater Certificate and key vaya CA in node js

Tags: x509certificate, x509, ca, forge, x509trustmanager

I want to implement microservices in node js. which will generator the Certificate with the help of any CA Certificate and also I can store some data in Certificate?
the same  Certificate I can validate by the same CA Certificate.

please help me any best way

Answer (score 0):

There is a tutorial on https://gist.github.com/Soarez/9688998 on how to do it with OpenSSL via CLI.

There is https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/crypto.html that wraps a lot of OpenSSL commands in JavaScript, but I don't thinks it covers everything.

Why do you want to automate your Public Key Infrastructure in NodeJS? That should be part of the infrastructure, not the application server.

There's things like XCA to manage them, too: https://hohnstaedt.de/xca/.